# What is the inflection point for this equation?

Tags: calculus

$$f(r) = 
−A/
r^2
 + 
B/
r^3
$$

I took the second derivative and end up with and r= -4B/2B but it was wrong, why ?

Comment: Are the denominators supposed to be $2r$ and $3r$ or $r^{2}$ and $r^{3}$? Also, $r=-4B/2B=-2$.

Comment: Sign problem, plus typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by rewriting the function as: $$f(r)=-Ar^{-2}+Br^{-3}$$ Applying power rule, we have $$f'(r)=2Ar^{-3}-3Br^{-4},$$ and another use of power rule gives us $$f''(r)=-6Ar^{-4}+12Br^{-5}=\frac{-6A}{r^4}+\frac{12B}{r^5}=\frac{-6Ar+12B}{r^5}$$ Can you take it from there (and see how I got the equations above)?

Comment: Same as what I did

Comment: Good! What did you do from there?

Comment: I did not merge them in one factor, I took the common factor 6r^-4

Comment: Then I end up with this answer r= -4B/2B

Comment: Okay, if you factored out $6r^{-4},$ then what was your other factor?

Comment: 2A+4Br^-1 that was the second one

Comment: That is not correct. $$6r^{-4}\cdot(2A+4Br^{-1})=12Ar^{-4}+24Br^{-5},$$ which is not the second derivative of $f.$ Instead, you should have $-A+2Br^{-1}$ as the other factor. Does that fix the issue?

Comment: Nope it did not, because I could it seems that I took 3 instead of 6. But still what is the inflection point ?

Comment: Well, $6r^{-4}$ cannot be $0,$ and is only undefined for $r=0,$ which isn't in the domain of the original function, anyway, so that factor won't give us an inflection point. Likewise, $-A+2Br^{-1}$ is only undefined at $r=0,$ so the only way we'll get an inflection point from that factor is if $$0=-A+2Br^{-1}.$$ Can you solve that one for $r$?

Comment: Incidentally, the least power of $r$ in the second derivative is $-5,$ not $-4,$ so it would be better to use $6r^{-5}$ as your common factor. Then you have $$f''(r)=6r^{-5}(-Ar+2B),$$ which makes things nicer.